# Can't run my jar file on html

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I can't run my jar file, MatadorClean.jar on HTML
I have tried different browsers but nothing works

In my code i have extended Applet in GUIController (i dont know if it is the right class to extend Applet) i have tried extending Applet in other classes but it's nothing working.

```
package game.boundaries;

import game.entities.Player;
import game.resources.FieldData;
import game.util.XMLReader;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 * Handles indirection between the supplied gui and the game
 */
public class GUIController extends Applet implements Outputable{

// Fields and cards
XMLReader reader;
int[] fieldType;
Color[] fieldColor;
String[] fieldTitle;
String[] fieldDescription;
String[] fieldSubtext;
String[] cards;
GUIBoundary gui;




// Constructors
public GUIController(String langFilePath) {
    this.reader = new XMLReader(langFilePath);
    this.fieldType = new int[FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length];
    this.fieldColor = new Color[FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length];
    this.fieldTitle = new String[FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length];
    this.fieldDescription = new String[FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length];
    this.fieldSubtext = new String[FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length];
    this.initializeBoard();
    gui = new GUIBoundary(fieldTitle, fieldDescription, fieldSubtext, fieldType, fieldColor);
}


// Methods

/***********************************************
 * Displays the dices in the gui for the player*
 * @param dice
 ***********************************************/

@Override
public void setDice(int[] dice){
    gui.setDice(dice);
}
/************************************************************************
 * Sets a hotel on the gui, if the player has enough houses on the field*
 *                                                                      *
 * @param hasHotel boolean to show if a hotel i present                 *
 * @param fieldNo fieldNo for the field to set a hotel                  *
 ************************************************************************/
@Override
public void setHotel(boolean hasHotel, int fieldNo) {
    gui.setHotel(hasHotel, fieldNo);
}
/**********************************************************************
 * Displays a specific amount of houses on a specific field on the gui*
 *                                                                    *
 * @param houseCount the amount of houses to display                  *
 * @param fieldNo the specific field to show the houses on            *
 **********************************************************************/
@Override
public void setHouse(int houseCount, int fieldNo) {
    gui.setHouse(houseCount, fieldNo);
}

/****************************************************************
 * Updating active player balance and position and displays     *
 * the dice rolled by the player                                *
 * @param dice
 * @param pos
 * @param balance
 * @param playerName
 ***************************************************************/
@Override
public void update(int[] dice, int pos, int balance, String playerName) {
    gui.update(dice, pos, balance, playerName);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Adds a new player to the board. using balance, name, and player #    *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player which should be added to the board  *
 * @param balance Starting balance of player                            *
 * @param playerNumber 0-5, otherwise error will occur                  *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void addPlayer(String playerName, int balance, int playerNumber) {
    gui.addPlayer(playerName, balance, playerNumber);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Clears all owners from the interactive gameboard.                    *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void removeAllOwners(){
    gui.removeAllOwners();
}

/************************************************************************
 * Removes the owner of a specific field so that the field is empty     *
 * and can be bought by another player.                                 *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param fieldNumber The number of the field 1-40                      *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void removeOwner(int fieldNumber){
    gui.removeOwner(fieldNumber);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message in the interface which is the playername and the     *
 * position of that player                                              *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of active player who has moved                *
 * @param pos The position where the player is on the board             *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showUpdateMessage(String playerName, int pos){
    String s1  = reader.getElement("positionUpdate", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + " " + (pos+1);
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a welcome message when the application have opened.            *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showWelcome() {
    gui.showMessage(reader.getElement("welcome", 0));
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message stating who is the starting player.                  *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player who is starting                     *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showStartingPlayer(String playerName){
    String s1 = reader.getElement("starting", 0);
    String msg = playerName + " " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message with the last player standing in the game and who    *
 * therefore is the winner of the game.                                 *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player who won the game                    *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showWinner(String playerName) {
    gui.showMessage(playerName + " " + reader.getElement("winner", 0));
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message with the player whose turn it is next. This          *
 * method doesn't have any real function other than that.               *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param name Name of the player who is next in throwing the dice.     *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showNextPlayerTurn(String name){
    String s1 = reader.getElement("doNothing", 0);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message in the interface with the amount of money that       *
 * has been withdrawn from a players account for one of several         *
 * reasons.                                                             *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player whose account is withdrawn from     *
 * @param amount Amount of money that has been withdrawn                *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showWithdrawMessage(String playerName, int amount) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("withdraw", 0);
    String s2 = reader.getElement("withdraw", 1);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + " " + amount + " " + s2;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a massage in the interface with the amount of money that has   *
 * been deposit into a players account for one of several reasons.      *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player whose account is deposit into       *
 * @param bonus
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showDepositMessage(String playerName, int bonus) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("deposit", 0);
    String s2 = reader.getElement("deposit", 1);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + " " + bonus + " " + s2;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message saying that a player hit a double if the two
 * dice shows identical number of eyes.
 *
 * @param name Name of player rolling the double.
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showIsDoublesMessage(String name){
    String s1 = reader.getElement("doubles", 0);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message which says that there are not enough money in the    *
 * account to spend on a certain item.                                  *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player that doesn't have enough money      *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showNotEnoughBalanceMessage(String playerName) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("lowBalance", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a massage that money has been transferred from one players     *
 * account to another players account                                   *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player who's having money taken from him   *
 * @param ownerName Name of player who owns the field and is having     *
 *          money transferred to his account.                           *
 * @param amount Amount of money being transferred between the players  *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showTransferMessage(String playerName, String ownerName, int amount) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("transfer", 0);
    String s2 = reader.getElement("transfer", 1);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + " " + amount + " " + s2 + " " + ownerName;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message saying that the player who is trying to buy a field  *
 * didn't succeed in buying it.                                         *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player not succeeding in buying a field    *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showNotBoughtMessage(String playerName) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("declinedBuy", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message that a field has been bought.                        *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player that has just bought the field      *
 * @param fieldNumber The number of the field that has been bought      *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showFieldBoughtMessage(String playerName, int fieldNumber) {
    gui.setFieldOwners(playerName, fieldNumber);
    String s1 = reader.getElement("acceptedBuy", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * This method will change the status of a field if it changes owner    *
 * or is bought by a player.                                            *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player getting ownership of the field.     *
 * @param fieldNumber Identification number of field changing ownership *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void setFieldOwners(String playerName, int fieldNumber){
    gui.setFieldOwners(playerName, fieldNumber);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message that the player have to roll the dice to find out    *
 * how much money he has to pay when he lands on another players        *
 * LaborCamp field.                                                     *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player who has to roll the dice.           *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showRollingDiceForRent(String playerName) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("rollForRent", 0);
    String btnRoll = reader.getElement("roll", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, btnRoll);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message saying that the active player has passed 'start' and *
 * therefore will receive an amount of money.                           *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param name Name of player passing the 'start'-field                 *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showPassStartMessage(String name){
    String s1 = reader.getElement("pass", 0);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message that the active player has got no more money in      *
 * his account and therefore is broke.                                  *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param playerName Name of player who is broke                        *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showBrokeMessage(String playerName) {
    gui.removeAllCars(playerName);
    String s1 = reader.getElement("broke", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message saying that the player is still imprisoned as a      *
 * result of not having a get-out-of-jail card.                         *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param name Name of player who is still imprisoned.                  *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showNoCardMessage(String name) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("imprisoned", 2);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message that a player that has landed on a 'Prøv lykken'-    *
 * field and got a get-out-of-jail card.                                *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param player The player who has received a get-out-of-jail card     *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showGetPrisonCardMessage(String player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("imprisoned", 3);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);

}

/************************************************************************
 * Shows a message that the player has to go to prison.                 *
 *                                                                      *
 * @param player The player that has been imprisoned.                   *
 ***********************************************************************/
@Override
public void showDoTimeMessage(String player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("imprisoned", 1);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}


@Override
public void showCardMessage(String playerName, int cardNo) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("cards", cardNo);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showCardMessage(msg);
}

@Override
public void showEnoughPropertys(String name) {
    String msg = name + ": " + reader.getElement("noMore", 0);
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

@Override
public void showNoPropertys(String name) {
    String msg = name + ": " + reader.getElement("noMore", 1);
    gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, "Ok");
}


@Override
public void showImprisonedMessage(String name2) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("imprisoned", 0);
    String msg = name2 + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}


@Override
public void showCard(String text) {
    gui.showCard(text);
    gui.getUserButtonPressed("", "OK");
}


@Override
public void showPlayerIsOwner(String playerName) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("isOwner", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}


@Override
public void showHousesOnFieldMessage(Player player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("protertiesHere", 0);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}


@Override
public void showDontSell(Player player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("protertiesHere", 1);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}


@Override
public void showParkingMessage(Player player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("parking", 0);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    gui.showMessage(msg);
}

//Player prompt methods

@Override
public void promptRollDice(String playerName) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("rollDice", 0);
    String btnRoll = reader.getElement("roll", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1;
    gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, btnRoll);
}


@Override
public String promptPlayerName(int playerNumber, boolean error) {
    String s1, s2, msg;
    if(error){
        msg = reader.getElement("promptName", 2);
    }
    else{
        s1 = reader.getElement("promptName", 0);
        s2 = reader.getElement("promptName", 1);
        msg = s1 + " " + playerNumber + " " + s2;
    }
    return gui.promptPlayerName(msg);
}


@Override
public boolean promptTax(String playerName, int taxAmount, int percentAmount) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("taxChoice", 0);
    String s2 = reader.getElement("taxChoice", 1);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + "(" + percentAmount + ") " + s2 + " " + taxAmount;
    String btnPercent = reader.getElement("taxButton", 0) + "(" + percentAmount + ")";
    String btnTaxAmount = String.valueOf(taxAmount);
    String result;
    result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, btnPercent, btnTaxAmount);

    return result.equals(btnPercent);
}


@Override
public boolean promptBuy(String playerName, int price) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("buy", 0);
    String yes = reader.getElement("yes", 0);
    String no = reader.getElement("no", 0);
    String msg = playerName + ": " + s1 + " " + price;
    return gui.promptYesNo(msg, yes, no);
}


@Override
public int PromptPrison(String playerName) {
    //choice for prisoncard
    String msg = reader.getElement("prison", 0);
    String c1 = reader.getElement("prison", 1);
    String c2 = reader.getElement("prison", 2);
    String c3 = reader.getElement("prison", 3);
    String c4 = reader.getElement("prison", 4);
    String result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, c1,c2,c3,c4);

    if(result.equals(c1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(result.equals(c1)){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(result.equals(c3)){
        return 3;
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean promptBuyProperty(String name, int i) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("buy", 2);
    int price = i;
    String yes = reader.getElement("yes", 0);
    String no = reader.getElement("no", 0);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1 + " " + price;
    String result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, yes,no);
    return result.equals(yes);
}


@Override
public boolean promptSellProperty(String name, int i) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("sell", 1);
    String yes = reader.getElement("yes", 0);
    String no = reader.getElement("no", 0);
    int price = i;
    String msg = name + ": " + s1 + " " + price;
    String result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, yes,no);

    return result.equals(yes);
}


@Override
public int promptAction(String name) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("action", 0);
    String msg = name + ": " + s1;
    String c1 = reader.getElement("buy", 1);
    String c2 = reader.getElement("sell", 0);
    String c3 = reader.getElement("nothing", 0);
    return gui.promptAction(msg, c1,c2, c3);
}


@Override
public int promptGameState() {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("load", 0);
    String c1 = reader.getElement("load", 1);
    String c2 = reader.getElement("load", 2);
    String result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(s1, c1,c2);

    if (result.equals(c1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 2;
    }
}


@Override
public String promptLoadAction(String[] games){
    String s1 = reader.getElement("load", 2);
    String result = gui.promptLoadAction(s1, games);
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean promptSellFields(Player player) {
    String s1 = reader.getElement("sell", 2);
    String c1 = reader.getElement("yes", 0);
    String c2 = reader.getElement("no", 0);
    String msg = player + ": " + s1;
    String result = gui.getUserButtonPressed(msg, c1,c2);

    return result.equals(c1);
}
//Initialize text on gui

@Override
public void initializeBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA.length; i++){
        switch(FieldData.FIELDTYPE_DATA[i]){
            case REFUGE:
                fieldType[i] = 0;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("get", 0) + " " + FieldData.FIELDRENT1_DATA[i];
                break;
            case TAX:
                fieldType[i] = 1;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("pay", 0) + " " + FieldData.FIELDRENT1_DATA[i];
                break;
            case TERRITORY:
                fieldColor[i] = FieldData.fieldColor[i];
                fieldType[i] = 2;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("ownable", 0) + " " + FieldData.FIELDBUYPRICE_DATA[i] +
                        ", " + reader.getElement("territory", 0) + " " +FieldData.FIELDRENT1_DATA[i];
                break;
            case LABOR_CAMP:
                fieldType[i] = 3;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("ownable", 0) + " " + FieldData.FIELDBUYPRICE_DATA[i] +
                        ", " + reader.getElement("laborCamp", 0);
                break;
            case FLEET:
                fieldType[i] = 4;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("ownable", 0) + " " + FieldData.FIELDBUYPRICE_DATA[i] +
                        ", " + reader.getElement("fleet", 0);
                break;
            case PRISON:
                fieldType[i] = 5;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("fine", 0)+ " " + "Kr. 1000";
                break;
            case START:
                fieldType[i] = 6;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("bonus", 0) + " " + "Kr. 4000";
                break;

            case LUCKYCARD:
                fieldType[i] = 7;
                fieldDescription[i] = reader.getElement("lucky", 0);
                break;
        }
        fieldTitle[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
        fieldSubtext[i] = reader.getElement(FieldData.FIELDNAME_DATA[i], 0);
    }
}
}
```

This is the HTML file i am running:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <APPLET ARCHIVE="MatadorClean.jar" CODE="GUIController.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=200>
 </APPLET>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). The rest of the browsers (that have not removed the plug-in completely) run a Java that insists on code being digitally signed by a certificate from a CA. Given you have not explicitly mentioned code signing, I would guess that has not happened.

Comment: BTW - it doesn't take 628 lines of code to demonstrate an inability to load an applet. It would probably be the same with just 40 LOC..